# CSS Circle Transition with Chevron in the middle

Tags: css

I want to get a play button just like the one found [here](https://codepen.io/stevenfabre/pen/DvBei).  However rather than a play button out of the border I'd like it to be a chevron right.  However both of these use `:before` and `:after` which I don't fully understand.

Could someone explain to me what those pseudo selectors are for and point me in the right directoin?  I'm trying to combine that example with [this chevron codepen](https://codepen.io/jonneal/pen/kptBs)

When all is said and done I'd like it to look like this.  I just thought it'd be really cool to get that nice trasition from the first example. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Chevrons as request, this is what I came up with. You may have to re-adjust the fine details such as border weight and positions.

```css
.chevron {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 0.25em solid #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.chevron::after {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0.25em 0.25em 0 0;
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 height: 0.45em;
 /*left: 0.15em;*/
 position: relative;
 top: 0.15em;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 0.45em;
}

.chevron.right:after {
 left: 0;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.chevron.bottom:after {
 top: 0;
 transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.chevron.left:after {
 left: 0.25em;
 transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Chevron (top) <span class="chevron top"></span>
<p>Chevron (right) <span class="chevron right"></span>
<p>Chevron (bottom) <span class="chevron bottom"></span>
<p>Chevron (left) <span class="chevron left"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone else may be able to explain it better but the way I think of it is kind of like generating an html element from within css.

Something along the lines of:  "for every element of "___", add a nameless sub-element at the beginning (:before) or end (:after) and style it in the following way..". At this point it's probably worth noting that other than the order they appear in, there is no difference between ':before' and ':after'.

The only way it really differs from any other element in a practical sense is you need to specify the 'content' attribute (even if its just an empty '').

so for example, if you had the chevron as a .png image:

```
.circle{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.circle::after{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-image: url('../path/chevron.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Other alternatives would be:

- Setting the content to '>', instead of the background-image solution.
- Styling the :after element to be a triangle, using this [css trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), instead of the background-image solution.

The transitions are a separate issue. If you need help with those aswell let me know.